# Does publishing an article in another language on an English website affect the optimization of the website?

Tags: seo, google

I am the webmaster of an English website. I want to publish articles in other languages ​​on this English website. Will Google recognize the duplicate articles? How will this affect my website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google doesn’t see translated content as duplication. The reason for this is that when you translate text from one language to another, enough changes are made that you essentially have new content on your hands.

Sounds simple, right? Well, it is – as long as you get professional translation. If you use software to translate your content, you won’t get the necessary changes to grammar structure and wording to create “new” content. Instead, each word is basically swapped for the closest dictionary alternative and that will be seen as duplicate content by Google.

You’ll also see on the Google Search Console site that “text translated by an automated tool without human review or curation before publishing” is enough grounds for a search penalty. This also applies to WordPress plugins and other free translation tools you may find online.

**Google does not want you to use Google Translate**

Google invests a lot of money into its own translation tool, but the search provider does not want you to use it for translating pages. Don’t expect any favours from its search team for using Google Translate, because you’ll be disappointed.

The reason is simple: large chunks of machine translated text that haven’t been reviewed by a professional will make little or no sense to anyone. Google doesn’t want that kind of experience littering its results pages – so forget Google Translate and any other automated software.

Get a professional translator to handle your multilingual content and you’ll be safe from Google penalties. More importantly, you’ll be engaging with your overseas markets in the way you need to.

Comment: Thank you very much for reminding me that if I publish articles in other languages ​​on an English site, will my site be punished by Google?

Comment: no but if you will use translator, google will punished your site in future at any time

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your help.